# How to get an area as image in Adobe InDesign with Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I want to develop a script for InDesign CS5. I need to take a selected area and need to convert it to image. Is there a way to do this. Also I need to post that image to an web page.

Can I do this by Javascript or needed to learn InDesign plugin development with c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it, with scripting an selected object or objects can be exported like below..

Assumed you have made selection on dcoument

```
var myObj = app.activeWindow.activePage.groups.add(app.selection);
myObj.exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, myFile, false);
myObj.ungroup();
```